# how to write semi join queries in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to write semi join query in cypher. For example, I want to find professors such that professor has at least one student with grade more than 9.0 in following graph:[Sample Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ntZm.png)

So output should be following for Sample Graph:

```
P2
P3
```

This will be done in SQL in following way:

```
Select Professor.name
From Professor
where exists (
                select * from Student
                where Student.grade >= 9.0 and
                Student.guide_id = Professor.id
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, for example, we add data on professors and students as follows:

```
UNWIND RANGE(1,1000) as i
 WITH 'professor_' + toInt(rand()*20) as pname, 
      'student_' + i as sname
 MERGE (P:Professor:Person {name: pname})
 MERGE (S:Student:Person   {name: sname}) SET S.grade = rand()*10
 MERGE (P)-[:guide]->(S)
```

Query a list of professors whose students have a grade >= 9.0:

```
MATCH (P:Professor)-[:guide]->(S:Student) WHERE S.grade >= 9.0
RETURN distinct P
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this cypher query applies "distinct" which will be very costly operation if  (P:Professor)-[:guide]->(S:Student) size is large. I was looking for the query that starts from professor and go to student nodes by utilizes edges and check student grades condition. If that is possible please reply with that.

Comment: @SumitNeelam I think this is the best option.

Comment: @stdob-- I think there's something wrong with your creation Cypher code. I'm seeing multiple professor nodes with the same names...I think students likely has the same problem. It's like the MERGE statements aren't really doing merging. Is there some kind of weird interaction when calculated values are involved?

Comment: Despite the above observation, I don't think it changes the correctness of your final answer. @SumitNeelam, given your requirements, I don't think there is a way to do this without using "distinct". The EXISTS() clause can only be applied to a pattern...not a pattern with predicates, and that's the only option I know of to avoid the need for distinct. You can use PROFILE before the query to see how Cypher is executing it

Comment: You can compare stdob--'s query with this one (using PROFILE) to see if there's any significant difference ----   PROFILE MATCH (p:Professor) WITH p MATCH (p)-[:guide]->(s:Student) WHERE s.grade >= 0.9 RETURN DISTINCT p

Comment: Well, I guess you could use WITH P, COLLECT(S) as students RETURN P to avoid the distinct, but really the COLLECT operation is likely to be more costly than DISTINCT. You can always compare if needed, but I think DISTINCT should be a fairly quick operation.

Comment: @InverseFalcon You're right. I corrected the data add query.